Replacing keywords in a DOCX file via PHP
Im trying to do an offline file filler (but they specifically asked for a browser experience so aigth) for a company that does the same paperwork over and over again. they assigned me to do a fairly simple "fill the form and trigger a download with the filled form.docx" situation.
i havent been able to make the text actually change, it does download the "filled" form, but the placeholder_text doesnt change
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    
    // Get the selected option from the form
    $selectedOption = $_POST['selected_option'];
    echo "Selected Option: " . htmlspecialchars($selectedOption); 
    // Load the template document
    $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('ver.docx');

    // Replace the placeholder text with the selected option
    $templateProcessor->setValue('placeholder_text', $selectedOption);

    // Save the modified document
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('VEREDICTO.docx');

    // Download the file
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="VEREDICTO.docx"');
    readfile('VEREDICTO.docx');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Invalid request method.";
}

$templateProcessor->setValue('placeholder_text', $selectedOption); is our toublemaker here, most probably.

What does your template file look like?

As per the documentation https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html the template file should be like these : ${placeholder_text} Are you having the same template format?
